# beautifulsoup несколько значений в regular expression

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, beautiful-soup, re

При поиске тэгов с помощью регулярных выражений необходимо задать несколько значений

```
get_link = soup.find('a', text=re.compile('about us' or 'о компании').get('href')
```

Это работает, но находит только первое значение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно задать несколько значений для поиска в регулярных выражениях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `|`:

```
(about us|о компании)
```